# Using arduino as a remote control

Tags: ir

I have old Sony amplifier (F117R) and CD player (CDP-590), both equipped with IR remote controls. The problem is that I bought them as vintage without remotes.

I have a rough idea how to build dedicated RC for both units but I'm missing the essential part - how is the signal encoded for the units?

I can find tutorials where the can be taught the codes from working remote control and how to build universal RC from that.

Is there any chance where to find IR codes for Hi-Fi units remote controls?

Comment: Just a little suggestion on an alternative approach:
https://www.ebay.ie/itm/Original-Sony-RM-S310-Remote-Control-for-TA-F410R-F411R-Audio-System-Tested/264447792621
https://www.ebay.ie/itm/Remote-Control-For-Sony-CDP-590-CDP-391-CDP-M201-CDP-M301-Compact-CD-Player/274003755223

Comment: https://irq5.io/2012/07/27/infrared-remote-control-protocols-part-1/

Comment: http://hifi-remote.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: http://picprojects.org.uk/projects/sirc/sonysirc.pdf

Comment: http://www.righto.com/2010/03/understanding-sony-ir-remote-codes-lirc.html

Comment: IR remote controls are not simple enough to be properly addressed in much less than a book. You will find this article VERY useful. There are hundreds of codes that use this format and it is likely you will find what you need. http://www.remotecentral.com/features/irdisp1.htm